# How to display products in prestashop form manufacturers database in real time

Tags: prestashop

We need to create an auto parts online shop based on prestashop.
The shop needs to filter products by car make, model, year, etc and than pull products from manufacturers database. Than the client must be able to add those products to cart an place an order.

I can't find any module for that purpose and i do not know here to begin with this thing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have worked before in a project like this, you can achieve that with this module: [Filter Products Pro](https://addons.prestashop.com/es/busquedas-filtros/5545-filter-products-pro-buscador-avanzado-de-productos.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response Rolige. The module is ok for filter produscts by my needs but can this module work with products from antoher database ? in the module description i do not find such functionality.

Comment: No, the module works only with products of the shop, but you can create complex filters, like nested filters.

Comment: thanks but this module does not help me. i need something custom